# Mocking case classes with primitive types

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest

Consider following types structure:

```
trait HasId[T] {
    def id: T
}

case class Entity(id: Long) extends HasId[Long]
```

Let's say, we want to mock Entity class in some test.

```
val entityMock = mock[Entity]
Mockito.when(entityMock.id).thenReturn(0)
```

Playing such test results in throwing NullPointerException (in second line), probably because of scala compiler behaviour with wrapping primitive types (if we replace Long with String, test executes correctly).

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort. 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.Entity$MockitoMock$1085095743.id(Unknown Source)
at com.test.Test.<init>(Test.scala:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.genSuiteConfig(Runner.scala:1422)
at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$8(Runner.scala:1236)
```

This error affects only case classes, and mockito in 2.X versions.

Is there any known solution to handle this issue?

UPDATE: problem occurs in versions newer than 2.0.8-beta

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test class:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class StackOverflowTest extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar {

  "Bla" should
    "fsg ll ll" in {
      val entityMock = mock[Entity]
      when(entityMock.id).thenReturn(0)
      foo(entityMock)
    }

  def foo(entity: Entity) = {
    entity.id == 0
  }

}

trait HasId[T] {
  def id: T
}

case class Entity(id: Long) extends HasId[Long]
```

Here is my sbt file:

```
name := "scalaExperiments"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % Test

libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "2.0.2-beta" % Test
```

Compiles and passes successfully.

Comment: it turns out, that mockito version 2.0.8-beta it the last one, for which it works correctly - every newer version fails

Comment: it actually doesn't answer my question, problem just doesn't yet occurs in that beta version of library