# Disable value classes unwrapping

Tags: scala, jvm, scalac

Is it possible in scala compiler to disable unwrapping of value classes?

disclaimer why I need this - because of mockito failures when mocking some specific class hierarchy ([Mocking case classes with primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586094/mocking-case-classes-with-primitive-types))

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the compiler to use non-primitive types...

```
case class Entity(id: java.lang.Long) extends HasId[java.lang.Long]
```